# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardTypeConverter.<init>(java.util.function.Supplier)'

Tags: spring, apache-camel, spring-context

I moved my application to spring 5.3.14 and facing below error

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardTypeConverter.(java.util.function.Supplier)'

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't use screenshots, instead include your `pom.xml`. Your question is tagger with `apache-camel`, when using Camel you are tied to versions of Spring supported by the version of apache camel you are using. Seems to me that that isn't the case.

Comment: Looking at Apache Camel 2.18 it is build using Spring Boot 1.4.x which won't support Spring 5 nor newer versions of Spring Integration. So you cannot upgrade to 5.3.x without upgrading Apache Camel as well. Use supported versions of the frameworks you are using, currently you aren't.

Comment: Thanks..Thats help me to resolve my issue